# HTTPS Server on Android Device Using NanoHttpd

Tags: android, ssl, https, wss, nanohttpd

I am trying to run an HTTPS Server on an Android device using NanoHttpd (my final goal is to run WSS server on Android). I successfully ran HTTP Server and Websocket using NanoHttpd on Android. I generated the key on MAC using this command and copied it onto my device:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore key.keystore -storepass keypass -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

I wrote the following code:

```
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
keyStore.load(stream, keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory
           .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePwd.toCharArray());
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
server.makeSecure(sc.getServerSocketFactory());
server.start();
```

I tested this on Chrome 38 and 42 with "Minimum SSL/TLS" flag set to "SSLv3". But when I want to connect to the server I keep receiving "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" error.

I tried different instances of protocol (SSL/TLS), on multiple machines, and browsers. I tried NanoHttpd SSLServerSocketFactory method. But the error is the same.

I already looked at some samples including:
https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/issues/139

Does anyone have any comment on this?

Comment: On which Android version do you execute the server?

Comment: It's a LG VS985 phone with Android version 5.0.1

Comment: you get this to work?

Answer (score 10):

After Hours of toil, I've got it!

Here is MY (working) code:

```
// I placed this block right below my class declaration so it runs
// as soon as the class is defined. (this is for localhost testing ONLY!!!!)    
static {
    //for localhost testing only
    javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
    new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

        public boolean verify(String hostname,
                javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
            if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

// then in an init function, I set it all up here
this.secureAppServer = new NanoHTTPD(9043);
File f =new File("src/main/resources/key001.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", f.getAbsolutePath());
this.secureAppServer.setServerSocketFactory(new SecureServerSocketFactory(NanoHTTPD.makeSSLSocketFactory("/" +f.getName(), "myawesomepassword".toCharArray()), null));

this.secureAppServer.start();
```

Here is the actual NanoHttpd Test case which illustrates exactly how its done Nano style.

```
package fi.iki.elonen;

import java.io.File;

/*
 * #%L
 * NanoHttpd-Core
 * %%
 * Copyright (C) 2012 - 2015 nanohttpd
 * %%
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 *    list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * 
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
 *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
 *    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * 3. Neither the name of the nanohttpd nor the names of its contributors
 *    may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without
 *    specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND
 * ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
 * WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.
 * IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT,
 * INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING,
 * BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE
 * OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 * #L%
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.SecureServerSocketFactory;

public class SSLServerSocketFactoryTest extends HttpServerTest {

    @Test
    public void testSSLConnection() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpTrace httphead = new HttpTrace("https://localhost:9043/index.html");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httphead);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        Assert.assertEquals(9043, this.testServer.getListeningPort());
        Assert.assertTrue(this.testServer.isAlive());
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreatePassesTheProtocolsToServerSocket() throws IOException {
        // first find the supported protocols
        SecureServerSocketFactory secureServerSocketFactory = new SecureServerSocketFactory(NanoHTTPD.makeSSLSocketFactory("/keystore.jks", "password".toCharArray()), null);
        SSLServerSocket socket = (SSLServerSocket) secureServerSocketFactory.create();
        String[] protocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();

        // remove one element from supported protocols
        if (protocols.length > 0) {
            protocols = Arrays.copyOfRange(protocols, 0, protocols.length - 1);
        }

        // test
        secureServerSocketFactory = new SecureServerSocketFactory(NanoHTTPD.makeSSLSocketFactory("/keystore.jks", "password".toCharArray()), protocols);
        socket = (SSLServerSocket) secureServerSocketFactory.create();
        Assert.assertArrayEquals("Enabled protocols specified in the factory were not set to the socket.", protocols, socket.getEnabledProtocols());
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", new File("src/test/resources/keystore.jks").getAbsolutePath());
        this.testServer = new TestServer(9043);
        this.testServer.setServerSocketFactory(new SecureServerSocketFactory(NanoHTTPD.makeSSLSocketFactory("/keystore.jks", "password".toCharArray()), null));
        this.tempFileManager = new TestTempFileManager();
        this.testServer.start();
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(100L);
            while (!this.testServer.wasStarted()) {
                Thread.sleep(100L);
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > 2000) {
                    Assert.fail("could not start server");
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        this.testServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: ONE NOTE: Nano tries to load the keystore as a resource stream, so the KeyStore MUST reside in src/main/resources (which is why I've set that as a hard path). Seems like this is a security feature ;).

Comment: Watch out on publicly posting your passwords

Comment: you mean you stored the file `res` folder? I'm not able to find the the `.jks` file.

Comment: Um, what? `src/main/resources/key001.jks` is valid at build time, but not run time.

Comment: Thanks for the warning @DenysVitali, luckily these aren't REAL production passwords ;), all just for testing purposes.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman have you made any changes to your Java installation (i.e. regarding security jars??), and have you correctly installed your certificates on your rooted android device?

Comment: Will it work for any IP address accessed from the desktop browser? That IP wont be fix

Comment: Yes @Abishek it should, once your browser downloads the certificate

Answer (score 4):

The other answers didn't work for me. I had to create a BKS-V1 Keystore using a [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html) and save it to android [assets](http://code2care.org/2015/create-assets-folder-in-android-studio/) folder as "keystore.bks". Alternatively, You can also use the following code to make the KeyStore file then just open it using [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html) and change its type to BKS-V1.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.bks -storepass myKeyStorePass -validity 360 -keysize 2048 -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1  -validity 9999
```

I used the following code to make it work.

```
package com.example.myappname

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;

import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

public class Server extends NanoHTTPD {
    public Server(int port) throws IOException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(port);
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream keyStoreStream = context.get().getAssets().open("keystore.bks");
        keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "myKeyStorePass".toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "myCertificatePass".toCharArray());
        makeSecure(NanoHTTPD.makeSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keyManagerFactory), null);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    }
}
```

To use it just write the following code and you will have an HTTPS server running on your Android device.

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
server.start(NanoHTTPD.SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT, false);
```

This code is made possible thanks to the example provided in the following Github issue comment.

https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/issues/535#issuecomment-479269044

Comment: Ravi Patel, I used this to create https server, but when I hit request form web application I get handshake failed, web application doesn't have client certificate as it is one way authentication. How can we achieve https with only server side certificate.

Comment: @wasim you can try disabling the certificate verification on client side. It may solve the issue.

Comment: from Client web application server certificate is validated. So we will have only server certificate. Is it because the certificate I'm using is self signed?

Comment: Yes, It can happen if you are using self-signed certificate.

Comment: Ravi, thanks for the reply.
Is there a way to know if the nanohttp server has stopped? Like do we have any broadcast so that if server is stopped after few min/hr we can start again.

Comment: @wasim You can run it in a Foreground Service, and it won't be stopped. I don't think there is an official way to detect it.

Comment: @RaviPatel it works when i change the key type to BKS-V1. But i got another issue: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:286)
Could you please tell me how to resolve?

Comment: @kollein Does this error happen when you open the server URL on your browser?

Comment: @RaviPatel actually, i'm building an android app and i serve it as a local server.
it works when i import the certificate into the keystore.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modified from Decoded's solution since I was not able to use JKS type of keystore.

Instead I use Keystore Explorer to generate a BKS key. 
Select BKS-V1 as type of the new KeyStore, then setup the NanoHTTPD server before start:

```
androidWebServer = new AndroidWebServer(port);

File f = new File("src/main/resources/localkey.bks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", f.getAbsolutePath());
androidWebServer.setServerSocketFactory(new AndroidWebServer.SecureServerSocketFactory(AndroidWebServer.makeSSLSocketFactory("/" + f.getName(), "yourKeyStorePass".toCharArray()), null));

androidWebServer.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

This link has solution: https://www.baeldung.com/nanohttpd#https

use keytool generate jks

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned
  -keystore keystore.jks -storepass your_password -validity 360
  -keysize 2048 -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1  -validity 9999
```

move keystore.jks to project src/main/resources

and use following code:

```
public class HttpsExample  extends NanoHTTPD {
 
    public HttpsExample() throws IOException {
        super(8080);
        makeSecure(NanoHTTPD.makeSSLSocketFactory(
          "/keystore.jks", "password".toCharArray()), null);
        start(NanoHTTPD.SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT, false);
    }
 
    // main and serve methods
}
```